# linq groupby Months and add any missing months to the grouped data

Tags: c#, linq

I have created a linq statement which seems to be working ok. I may or maynot have written it correctly however its returning my expected results.

```
     var grouped = RewardTransctions.GroupBy(t => new
        {
            t.PurchaseDate.Value.Month
        }).Select(g => new TransactionDetail()
        {
            Month =
                g.Where(w=>w.EntryType==1).Select(
                    (n =>
                     n.PurchaseDate.Value.Month))
                .First(),
            TransactionAmount = g.Count()
        });
```

Now the results are returning 5 values grouped by months. Is it possible to add the 7 other missing months with a TransactionAmount = 0 to them?

The reason for my madness is I am trying to bind these values to a chart and having my x axis based on months. Currently its only showing the 5 months of records. If my data doesnt return any value for a month I some how want to add in the 0 value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't `Month = g.Where(w=>w.EntryType==1).Select((n => n.PurchaseDate.Value.Month)).First()` just be `Month = g.Key`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple if you use `.ToLookup(...)`.

```
var lookup =
    (from w in RewardTransctions
     where w.EntryType == 1
     select w).ToLookup(w => w.PurchaseDate.Value.Month);

var grouped =
    from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    select new TransactionDetail()
    {
        Month = m,
        TransactionAmount = lookup[m].Count(),
    };
```

How's that for a couple of simple LINQ queries?

Comment: This is just pure art.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using LINQ to Objects, this query should do the trick:

```
var grouped = 
    from month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    select new TransactionDetail()
    {
        Month = month,
        TransactionAmount = RewardTransactions
            .Where(t => t.PurchaseDate.Value.Month == month).Count()
    };
```

When `RewardTransactions` however is an `IQueryable`, you should first call `AsEnumerable()` on it.

Comment: Fabulous! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it just like this:

```
var grouped =
    RewardTransctions.GroupBy(t => t.PurchaseDate.Value.Month).Select(
        g => new TransactionDetail { Month = g.Key, TransactionAmount = g.Count() }).ToList();
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
{
    if (grouped.Count(x => x.Month == i) == 0)
    {
        grouped.Add(new TransactionDetail { Month = i, TransactionAmount = 0 });
    }
}
```

It's not entirely LINQ, but straight forward. I also simplified your LINQ query a bit ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I guess If you do not use an anonymoustype(var), but create a custom type and do a .ToList() on your query that you can use .Add() on your list and bind the chart to the list.

Comment: He doesn't use an anonymous type. The result of his query is IEnumerable<TransactionDetail>. The use of var doesn't necessarily mean the use of an anonymous type.

Comment: Still if you use a ToList<TransactionDetail> you can simply add the missing parts.