# Linq missing months

Tags: .net, linq

I have a linq which groups prices by month works perfectly except I can't see the months which doesn't have data. what I am expecting If a month doesn't have data price should be 0.

```
List<decimal> osman1 = osman.GroupBy(i => new 
{ 
    Field1 = i.Field<DateTime>("CreateDate").Month 
})
.Select(group => group.Sum(i => Convert.ToDecimal(i["Price"])))
.ToList();
```

result osman1 is

> {221,103,352}

what I need is

> {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,221,0,103,352,0}

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq groupby Months and add any missing months to the grouped data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077006/linq-groupby-months-and-add-any-missing-months-to-the-grouped-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to do a group join:

```
var totalsByMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
      .GroupJoin(osman,
                 month => month,
                 record => record.Field<DateTime>("CreateDate").Month,
                 (month, records) => records.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Price")))
      .ToList();
```

(I've used `Field<decimal>` rather than `Convert.ToDecimal` as I think it's usually cleaner; change it if you need to, of course.)

Comment: perfect solution. I need more linq practise :) thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mert: The important thing here is that it's a *group* join rather than an inner join - which means you get a group (an empty group) when there are no matches on the "inner" set.