# c# linq extension Group and select data by quarter with missing months inside

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have data that consist of dates and sums.
I need to calculates sales sum by quarter.
The output returns array of sales sum by quarters, 
result[0] is sales sum for Q1, result[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077006/linq-groupby-months-and-add-any-missing-months-to-the-grouped-data) is sales sum for Q2 etc

For example input 'sales':

```
/// {} => { 0, 0, 0, 0}
/// {(1/1/2010, 10), (2/2/2010, 10), (3/3/2010, 10)} => { 30, 0, 0, 0 }
/// {(1/1/2010, 10), (4/4/2010, 10), (10/10/2010, 10)} => { 10, 10, 0, 10 }
```

I figured out how to group but have a problem with missing quarters.

```
sales.GroupBy(item => ((item.Item1.Date.Month - 1) / 3))
     .Select(x => new { Quarter = x.Key, Sum = x.Sum(item => item.Item2) })
```

One [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077006/linq-groupby-months-and-add-any-missing-months-to-the-grouped-data) is quite good but I couldn't manage it for my situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your data doesn't necessarily have all the quarters you should `left join` it to a collection of all the quarters. To create such use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var groupedSales = sales.GroupBy(item => ((item.Date.Month - 1) / 3))
                        .Select(x => new { Quarter = x.Key, 
                                           Sum = x.Sum(item => item.Amount) });

var result = (from quarter in Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
              join sale in groupedSales on quarter equals sale.Quarter into grouping
              from sale in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { Quarter = quarter, Sum = sale?.Sum ?? 0 }).ToList();
```

Some testing data:

```
List<dynamic> sales = new List<dynamic>
{
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,1,1), Amount = 10 },
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,2,2), Amount = 10 },
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,3,3), Amount = 10 },
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,4,4), Amount = 10 },
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,5,5), Amount = 10 },
   new { Date = new DateTime(2010,6,6), Amount = 10 },
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works. How this linq could be writeen with help of extension methods?
p.s. I've tried Join, Union, GroupJoin, but couldn't find proper solution for extension methods, This is important for me to get better understanding how it works.

Comment: @IIyaLabacheuski - I assume you mean with linq's method syntax instead of query syntax - check the link I gave you for left join. One of the examples uses the method syntax

Comment: yep. I got just a glance on it, bookmarked to dig in later. In the link is everything. Thx a lot!

Comment: This answer assumes that dates will be within one year. Any way to make it multi-year?

Comment: @SomaMbadiwe - group by both that and the year. Have a look at grouping by multiple values with linq